# How to prevent function from beeing called again using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using youtube iframe api to detect when video starts playing, sometimes it can happen that state changes to buffering and then again to playing, so `myFunction` gets executed more than once per session, how do I make it run only once?

```
if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    playing = true;
    player.mute();
    player.setPlaybackQuality('small');

    function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var videoData = player.getVideoData();
            var video_id = videoData['video_id'];
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url='https://url?viewcounter=' + video_id;
            Http.open("GET", url);
            Http.send();
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be easier to answer properly if you also included the code wherever `myFunction` is invoked, in addition to the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Boolean flag

```
var alreadyRun = false;
if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !alreadyRun) {
            playing = true;
            alreadyRun = true;
            player.mute();
            player.setPlaybackQuality('small');
    function myFunction() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        var videoData = player.getVideoData();
        var video_id = videoData['video_id'];
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url='https://url?viewcounter=' + video_id;
        Http.open("GET", url);
        Http.send();
      }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `playing` variable may already exist for that purpose, in which case OP could just add that to the conditional instead of creating another flag.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you could use a variable in your if statement, i.e:

```
var isplaying = false;

if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && isplaying === false) {
    isplaying = true;
    playing = true;
    player.mute();
    player.setPlaybackQuality('small');
    function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var videoData = player.getVideoData();
            var video_id = videoData['video_id'];
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url='https://url?viewcounter=' + video_id;
            Http.open("GET", url);
            Http.send();
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check also for if video is buffering so yt returns `YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING`

```js
if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && event.data !== YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING)  {
    playing = true;
    player.mute();
    player.setPlaybackQuality('small');

    function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var videoData = player.getVideoData();
            var video_id = videoData['video_id'];
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url='https://url?viewcounter=' + video_id;
            Http.open("GET", url);
            Http.send();
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable to run only 1 time.

```js
var sw_myFunction = false;

if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    playing = true;
    player.mute();
    player.setPlaybackQuality('small');

    function myFunction() {
        if(sw_myFunction) return;
        setTimeout(function(){
            var videoData = player.getVideoData();
            var video_id = videoData['video_id'];
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url='https://url?viewcounter=' + video_id;
            Http.open("GET", url);
            Http.send();
        }, 3000);
        sw_myFunction = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somethin is wrong, http request isn't called after 30 secs.
Full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
     var sw_myFunction = false;
     var player, playing = false;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          videoId: '<?php if (empty($vid)) {
    echo "YbJOTdZBX1g";
}
else {
    echo $vid;
}
 ?>',
          playerVars: {'controls': 0, 'fs': 0,'playsinline': 1 },         
          events: {
            'onError': onPlayerError, 
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

          function onPlayerStateChange(event) {


if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    playing = true;
    player.mute();
    player.setPlaybackQuality('small');
    var videoData = player.getVideoData();
    var video_id = videoData['video_id'];
    function myFunction() {
        if(sw_myFunction) return;
        setTimeout(function(){
            const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            const url='https://www.url.com?viewcounter=' + video_id;
            Http.open("GET", url);
            Http.send();
        }, 30000);
        sw_myFunction = true;
    }
}

      else if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED){     

       }

      else if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED){      

       }  

}
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
      }

function onPlayerError(event)
{       

}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Generally, you should add information like this by editing your question, instead of posting it as an answer.  That way people are less likely to miss it

Comment: To answer your question, the issue is that you've declared a function called `myFunction` in your code, but you need to call it with `myFunction()` in order for it to run.

Comment: Better yet, you could remove the `function myFunction() {` line entirely, along with the corresponding `}`, and just have the code run inline.